# Multiple content-types for request in webservice

Tags: java, design-patterns, content-type

I have one webservice which can take multiple content-types in request

```
text/plain 
application/json
```

Now, client can send any of them either json or text.
I have two options available on server

1. I can create separate apis for different content types
2. I can parse request data and check if its json or text?

What is better approach here?Is there a design pattern suited for this need?

Note: Management prefer to have one api which can support multiple content-types.

Comment: Though approach 1 is preferable,still depends on howdo you delegate the request,based on content types to subsequent APIs

Answer (score 1):

The client must include a [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header indicating the format of the entity they are sending to the server. If the server does not support the format which a client has sent, the expected response is [`415 Unsupported Media Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.16).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 1 and have the common logic placed in a seperate method. That way you let the API check and parse the input data for you.

Answer (score 0):

In http you use the "accept"- header to define what type you expect the response to be. The server delivers the content as defined in accept header, the default if it's not set or 406 - "Not acceptable" if the type is not supported

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: This would be the correct answer if the question was concerning a server with multiple outputs. Rather, the question is concerning a server with multiple inputs.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `@Path` annotations more thoroughly-

The `@javax.ws.rs.Path` annotation must exist on either the class and/or a resource method. If it exists on both the class and method, the relative path to the resource method is a concatenation of the class and method.

See this link https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Using__Path_and__GET___POST__etc..html